# How to use $(this) in custom jquery plug-in

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

This is my code

```
$('#J_todayComm').myScroll({
    ajaxUrl: $(this)
});
```

I want get `$(this)` -> `$('#J_todayComm')`, but It is `$(doucmen)`。

My plug-in code `myScroll.js`

```
$.fn.myScroll = function (options) {
    var s = $.extend({
        debug: false,
        threshold: 65,
        loading: false,
        ajaxUrl: '',
        ajaxMethod: 'GET',
        ajaxData: {},
        loadSuccess: function () {
        },
        template: function () {
            console.error("Need Template");
        }
    }, options);
    console.log(s.ajaxUrl); //I want it is $('#J_todayComm')
    // jquery对象
    var $self = this;
    // 原生DOM对象
    var self = this[0];
    ......
    function getDate() {
        if (!s.ajaxUrl) {
            console.error('Need url');
            return '';
        }
        $.ajax(s.ajaxUrl, {
            method: s.ajaxMethod,
            data: s.ajaxData,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (res) {
                ...
            },
            error: function () {
                ...
            }
        });
    }

    return $self;

};
```

How do I write code? Thx everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make the `this` keyword refer to the element in the selector, you need to change the scope of your call. You could do that by iterating through the elements using `each()`:

```
$('#J_todayComm').each(function() {
  var $el = $(this);
  $el.myScroll({
    ajaxUrl: $el.data('ajax-url'),
    // other settings...
  });
});
```

Comment: Thx,  you inspired me

Answer (score 0):

**code**

```
$.fn.extend({
  myScroll:function(){
    console.log(this);//這是你的本物件了
  }
})

$('#J_todayComm').myScroll();
```

change the other way to extend the fn then you don't depend on orign jquery funtion and can got `this` of you object (and without your `options`).

Comment: Thx, Upstairs maybe is what I want